# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: join(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, bool given

Tags: php, php-8.2

I have used such a code to display the captcha error on the login page that I have designed (this code is located in the `functions.php` file):

```
$error_codes =  join( ',' , $user->get_error_codes() );

$error_codes ->add( 'error_captcha', 'error_captcha' );
     return $error_codes;
```

But it keeps showing me the following error and I don't know what to do:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: join(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, bool given
```

Comment: Why not check what `get_error_codes` returns?

Comment: Hello. I have created a new question and put the complete codes there. Please check this question if possible:[The wrong display of the error related to the submission of the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77430579/the-wrong-display-of-the-error-related-to-the-submission-of-the-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your `$user->get_error_codes()` returns array or null: `implode(',' , $user->get_error_codes() ?: []);`
2. `$errorcodes->add` will throw error, because `implode` (`join` is alias) returns string. And string does not have any methods. Don't know what you want to do here

Comment: I changed it like this: `$errorcodes =  implode(',' , $user->get_error_codes() ?: null);` And then I got this error: 
`Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #1 ($pieces) must be of type array, string given`

Comment: I have also used this code on the page where I intend to display the error:  `$error_codes = explode( ',', $_REQUEST[ 'loginSite' ] );`

Comment: @Benjamin Change default value to array

Comment: I changed the code like this: `$error_codes = implode($_POST , $user->get_error_codes() ?: null);` But I got another fatal error which was solved by removing this code: `$error_codes ->add( 'error_captcha', 'error_captcha' );` Now the error is displayed on the page but it is wrong and the **captcha error** is not shown. I have edited my question and put the complete code.

Comment: @Benjamin So now it's different question. Please created new question and don't just edit current question with new error

Comment: I have created a new question, please check it: [The wrong display of the error related to the submission of the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77430579/the-wrong-display-of-the-error-related-to-the-submission-of-the-form)